# How to restore the files in wal and execute flush when restarting fails in Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.0?

Tags: database, flush, apache-iotdb, iotdb

What should I do if the flush command fails to persist the files in wal, resulting in the failure to restart Apache IoTDB? I use Version 0.13.0 of IoTDB, and the error message is: `231 - WAL detected, please stop insertion and run 'SET SYSTEM TO READONLY, then run 'flush' on IoTDB 0.12.1 before upgrading`. I didn't understand this error message, since my server can’t even start, I cannot execute the cli tool and generate flush. I tried to delete the files in wal, then import the wal files after successfully restarting IoTDB. However, these part of data is lost, and the `load` command cannot restore it. Anyone can explain this error to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error massage indicates to flush in the 0.12 version of Apache IoTDB. You can check if the java interface called by the platform to insert data is still the one of version 0.12. If so, since your version now is 0.13, you can directly replace it with the 0.13 Java interface.